# Python API request with variable params

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having a problem with API query in Python script. My query returns only 1000 results in XML-format page, not more. To get a next page with data, I should use a `NextPageToken` from current page. This token located in the end of XML-page. So, I need a cycle to get page - parse  - write data in file - extract a token and sand new query for a next page till the end.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

headers = {'log': 'admin',
           'pass': 'admin'}
param_token = {}

response_results = requests.get("https://10.10.1.0/results",headers=my_headers,params=param_token)

data_results = response_results.text
data_results_file = open("token.txt", "w", encoding='UTF-8')
data_results_file.write(data_results)
xml_data = open('token.txt', 'r', errors="ignore", encoding='UTF-8')
tree = ET.parse(xml_data)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter(tag='nextPageToken'):print(child.text)
```

This snippet returns me a first token, but how to reuse it and get a following page?

I think, here needs a definition, but not sure.
Help if you can, please.

p.s. sorry, if I describe deficiency - NextPageToken gets from first page and gives in second sending as a parameter (requests.get(...params='token'))

Comment: Usually, you pass it in the URL as a query string, or it can also be part of the headers, but it's impossible to say without knowing what API you're talking about. Pagination is almost always described in the API docs.

Comment: I described, 'NextPageToken' gives in the end of first XML-page. I need to use him as a param in request string. Documentation does not explain how to use him in a python script for a next query.

Comment: 1) My best guess, from your description, would be `requests.get("https://10.10.1.0/results",headers=my_headers,params={'NextPageToken': next_page_token})`, where the variable `next_page_token` is the token you found from the XML. 2) Is there really no example on the API documentation of how to use this token? Even for a different language?